# How do i install apache on my ubuntu 12.04 where it has virtualhost

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, php, httpd

According to the docs https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/httpd.html i have done following, and that is almost how i do always in my Fedora, but Ubuntu looks like its not working.

a) DNS to IP

```
$ echo "127.0.0.1  a" > /etc/hosts
$ echo "127.0.0.1  b" > /etc/hosts
```

b) Apache virtualhost

```
$ ls
1  2  default  default.backup  default-ssl
$ cat 1
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName a
 ServerAlias a
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/a/public
 <Directory /var/www/html/a/public>
    #AddDefaultCharset utf-8
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

$ cat 2
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName b
 ServerAlias b
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/b/public
 <Directory /var/www/html/b/public>
    #AddDefaultCharset utf-8
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

c) load into Apache and restart the service

```
$ a2ensite 1
$ a2ensite 2
$ a2dissite default
$ a2enmod rewrite
$ /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

d) Browse the new 2 hosts

```
$ firefox http://a
```

Does not work it goes always with `http://a` or `http://b` to `/var/www/html`

How do i fix it so that it goes to its own directory e.g: `http://a` goes to `/var/www/html/a/public` not `/var/www/html`?

Comment: Apache should work the same on any operating system its placed on.  The only difference is how you configure it on a given system.  Can be make this less localized to Ubuntu considering Fedora is also a Linux kernel the directions literally should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to find out what apache thinks it is doing is to run

`apachectl -S`

This will tell you all the configured virtual hosts and where they are defined. Perhaps that will help track down your issue?